# Spark - compute statistics for array columns (ArrayType)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization, catalyst

I am currently working with **Spark 2.4.3** and have to carry out some joins, for instance:

```
val res = df1.join(df2, Seq("x")).join(df3, Seq("y")).join(df4, Seq("z"))
```

where each of the DFs involved are created from a Hive Table which contains columns of ArrayType. 
For instance:

```
val df1 = spark.sql("SELECT x FROM TableWithArrayCols LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(xArray) explodedX as x")
```

As you can see, to create the DFs the required column(s) of **TableWithArrayCols** are exploded.

I would like the CBO to trigger the optimization for reordering joins. However, as far as I understood, this cannot occur because of lack of statistics for the array columns. Indeed, if I compute:

```
analyze table TableWithArrayCols compute statistics for columns xArray
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Column xArray in table `myDB`.`TableWithArrayCols` is of type
ArrayType(StringType,true), and Spark does not support statistics collection on this column type.;
```

My questions:

1) Can I manually add the statistic values (e.g. min, max, num_nulls, distinct_count) to the corresponding metadata? If yes, how? If not, is there an alternative solution?

2) Does manually adding the statistics result in automatically triggering the optimizations from the CBO?